# Start client fullscreen doesn't cover wibox

Tags: fullscreen, awesome-wm

When a client is started, it should be started fullscreen. I tried to configure this using rules but no matter what I do, the client doesn't cover the wibox.

What I have so far:

```
function set_fullscreen(c)
    mywibox[c.screen].ontop = false
    c.fullscreen = false
    c.fullscreen = true
    c.x = 0
    c.y = 0
    mywibox[c.screen].ontop = false
    c.fullscreen = false
    c.fullscreen = true
    c.x = 0
    c.y = 0
end

awful.rules.rules = {
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                     buttons = clientbuttons } },
    { rule = { class = "<name>" },
      properties = { fullscreen = true,
                     size_hints_honor = false,
                     focus = true }, 
      callback = set_fullscreen }
}
```

I have my wibox on the bottom and the application gets painted above the wibox. It also gets painted off-screen above, the size of the wibox. The application seems to have the correct size, but the wibox seems to be in the way.

When I toggle fullscreen for the application, when it is already running, fullscreen works as expected. The application does cover the wibox.

```
function toggle_fullscreen(c)
    c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen
end
```

I also have a signal handler that toggles ontop for the wibox when a focussed client's fullscreen property changes:

```
client.connect_signal("property::fullscreen", function (c)
    if c.fullscreen and c == client.focus then
        mywibox[c.screen].ontop = false
    else
        mywibox[c.screen].ontop = true
    end
end)
```

Nothing what I do seems to start the application in fullscreen, I always have to toggle manually. Anybody any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
client.connect_signal("property::fullscreen", function (c)
    if c.fullscreen and c == client.focus then
        mywibox[mouse.screen].visible = not mywibox[mouse.screen].visible
    else
        mywibox[mouse.screen].visible = not mywibox[mouse.screen].visible
    end
end)
```

Work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
function toggle_fullscreen(c)
    c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen
    --TODO store the existing ontop state
    c.ontop      = c.fullscreen
    c:raise()
end
```